# Gnome-Shell and Unity run at the same time

Tags: unity, ati, gnome

I have installed Ubuntu Oneiric and everything seemed to work fine, downloaded binary ATI Catalyst 11.9. After that installed Gnome Shell. Typed in Terminakl `gnome-shell --replace` but still there are problems, seems like unity is disturbing Gnome Shell, when I point my mouse to the top left of the screen which opens Applications/Windows menu. Last time somehow managed to uninstall unity completely and for the moment Gnome-Shell worked properly, but after reboot, everything crashed, wasn't even able to boot in. Any ideas ? Seemed for me like Unity was trying to show it's panel in the top of Gnome-Shell's panel.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're not supposed to switch between them like that. You log into a session running Unity or Gnome Shell from the display manager. In your example, it's not Unity that is interfering with Gnome Shell, but Gnome Shell that interferes with Unity. In other words; gnome-shell --replace doesn't properly shutdown Unity.

It would be very nice if Unity and Gnome Shell could cooperate on this so that you could just switch between them without logging out and back in, but this is in the future.

Comment: No no, I mean I change Session in LightDM, but the problem is the same.l I type Gnome-Shell --Replace, when I am logged into Gnome session. :)

Comment: Oh, ok. That's strange, I haven't had any problems switching between them, as long as I log out before starting the other shell.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me last night.  Had a quick look round today and it looks like this is a bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/855943

This suggests re-installing libgl1-mesa-glx is necessary after removing FGLRX.  The problem seems to be affecting Unity which, in turn is affecting Gnome Shell.  If this doesn't sort it there appear to be others reporting similar issues:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1849217
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/826771

Haven't been able to try any of these myself yet

Comment: But I don't remove FLGRX why would I ? It's needed for me as I have ATI Graphics